# How to get the object reference of a class

Tags: java

I have made two JAVA classes classA and classB in the same package. The classA consists of two labelFields and a button. And then I made 5 objects of classA inside classB. Now when click on the button of any object of classA which is inside classB. The logic for buttons click event i have written it inside classA. Now how can classA know which object's button was clicked from classB. I am developing an application for blackberry.

Comment: Could you post some of the code you're talking about?  The description you give is pretty confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Class A will only know what you tell it.  Class B can call the correct method of Class A for a given button, or pass the information about which button was clicked to Class A.

More information about your classes, and perhaps some code, would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use Implicit invocation. Wikipedia does a good explanation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_invocation

If this is what you want, I can add general java code for implementing it.